# Return JSON response in ISO-8859-1 with NodeJS/Express

Tags: node.js, json, express, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have built an API with Node and Express which returns some JSON. The JSON data is to be read by a web application. Sadly this application only accepts ISO-8859-1 encoded JSON which has proven to be a bit difficult.

I can't manage to return the JSON with the right encoding even though I've tried the methods in the Express documentation and also all tips from googling the issue.

The Express documentation says to use "res.set()" or "res.type()" but none of these is working for me. The commented lines are all the variants that I've tried (using Mongoose):

```
MyModel.find()
.sort([['name', 'ascending']])
.exec((err, result) => {
  if (err) { return next(err) }

  // res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=iso-8859-1')
  // res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=ansi')
  // res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=windows-1252')
  // res.type('application/json; charset=iso-8859-1')
  // res.type('application/json; charset=ansi')
  // res.type('application/json; charset=windows-1252')

  // res.send(result)
  res.json(result)
})
```

None of these have any effect on the response, it always turns into "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8".

Since JSON should(?) be encoded in utf-8, is it event possible to use any other encoding with Express?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the `lib/response.js` file in the Express source code (in your `node_modules` folder or at https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js) you'll see that `res.json` takes your `result`, generates the corresponding JSON representation in a JavaScript `String`, and then passes that string to `res.send`.

The cause of your problem is that when `res.send` (in that same source file) is given a `String` argument, it encodes the string as UTF8 and also forces the `charset` of the response to `utf-8`.

You can get around this by not using `res.json`.  Instead build the encoded response yourself.  First use your existing code to set up the Content-Type header:

```
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=iso-8859-1')
```

After that, manually generate the JSON string:

```
    jsonString = JSON.stringify(result);
```

then encode that string as ISO-8859-1 into a `Buffer`:

```
    jsonBuffer = Buffer.from(jsonString, 'latin1');
```

Finally, pass that buffer to `res.send`:

```
    res.send(jsonBuffer)
```

Because `res.send` is no longer being called with a `String` argument, it should skip the step where it forces `charset=utf-8` and should send the response with the `charset` value that you specified.